# How to implement zoomable ImageView inside ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview, android-pageradapter

My only problem is that when the Image is Zoomed, it is overlapping with the previous and next element of the pager.

**ViewPager Without Zoom**

[image]

**After Zoom Images Are overlapping**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery) library is exactly what I want but I still need some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use this library,

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView